# QuickLook Plugin Failing with sandboxing error

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, quicklook, appstore-sandbox

I have a QLPlugin that resides in my app's bundle. It worked on Mountain Lion and earlier, but now on Mavericks, only the thumbnail generator works. The preview generator fails with a sandboxing error in Console:

```
8/5/14 7:41:34.000 PM kernel[0]: Sandbox: QuickLookSatelli(98371) deny file-read-data <path to file>
```

Both the thumbnail and preview generators log this error, but a thumbnail still gets generated, whereas a preview does not. It runs (via `qlmanage`) in Xcode, logging some semi-related errors:

2014-08-05 19:39

```
:33.008 qlmanage[98314:303] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x912b, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2014-08-05 19:39:33.012 qlmanage[98314:303] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x3f27, name = 'com.apple.CFPasteboardClient'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2014-08-05 19:39:33.013 qlmanage[98314:303] Failed to allocate communication port for com.apple.CFPasteboardClient; this is likely due to sandbox restrictions
```

QuickLook plugins can't have an entitlements file, so what can I do?

Comment: I noticed that in my case it was just a bug in the code. Using qlmanage for debugging helped me.
`qlmanage -d4 -p test.mytype`